# Integrating JasperReports Server with an existing web application

Tags: jasper-reports, report, jasperserver

I have taken up a project to integrate JasperReports Server with an existing web application. I am using the community edition 4.5 of JRS. I was able to succesfully download and point it to my tomcat server and mysql databases. My question is: I want to re direct users from my web app to the JasperReports Server webapp and bypass the login screen of JasperReports Server. My web app uses LDAP validation. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer on this website http://ebookbrowse.com/jw11-jrsintegration-lukeshannon-pdf-d67595249. There is pdf file "Integrating and Deploying JasperReportsServer with Java Applications".

I successfully embedded JasperReports Server with HTTP from my Java web application using JSP.

Regards

Comment: The link doesn't show how.It's just a presentation but doesn't provide specific steps

Answer (score 0):

Sorry there is no way to do that .

Comment: Thank you for providing an answer. Do you have any documented reference for this? Even if something is true today things might change in the future, so having a reference to correlate is important.